# Organization Assets Library in SharePoint 2019 (On-Premise)

Tags: sharepoint-server, assets

Is it posible to create some kind of "Organization Assets Library" in Sharepoint 2019 (On-premise)?

Or can someone explain to me what tasks I have to perform so that users can select the corporate images from any site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the same problem in our organisation. What we are going to do is

1. Create an organisation library and it subfolders in the "portal" site collection (organisation home page). Set permission to read only for everyone except our "content managers".
2. Create the same folder hierarchy (with the same names) in all site collections. Set permission to read only for everyone.
3. Use a job to synchronise every night each library based on what is in the first one (in "portal").

It is acceptable because most of the time such library are not going to be modified very fast.

Comment: It's a good solution.
Thanks for share!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

"O[rganization Assets Library](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/organization-assets-library)" is Office 365 SharePoint Online feature, not available for SharePoint 2019 On-premise.

Comment: I know, but what I'm asking is if anyone can think of what the solution would be for an on-premise scenario